# Getting Null Pointer Exception while converting HTML to PDF using iText

Tags: java, itext7, html2pdf

Am using iText HTML to pdf when the HTML code fits one page it is generating but when the HTML code is too large it is not working
used Java Code HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlFile, pdfFile);, using itext7 html2pdf-2.1.6 is the version

java code

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;

public class html2pdf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String ws = "/workspace/wintmp/u02/ffsdev/templates/";
        File htmlFile = new File(ws+"QUOTE001.html.tpl.html");
        
        File pdfFile = new File(ws+"QUOTE001.pdf");
        
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlFile, pdfFile);

    }
}
```

below is the Working HTML code

```html
   
https://jsfiddle.net/praveenrk/L0nzbu7y/
```

not working

```html
   https://jsfiddle.net/praveenrk/0rvL2gx9/
```

and exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.getOccupiedAreaBBox(AbstractRenderer.java:1010)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.getBorderAreaBBox(AbstractRenderer.java:1020)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.drawBorder(AbstractRenderer.java:883)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.drawBorder(TableRenderer.java:1345)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.draw(TableRenderer.java:1093)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.drawChildren(AbstractRenderer.java:855)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.draw(BlockRenderer.java:580)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DocumentRenderer.flushSingleRenderer(DocumentRenderer.java:147)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:290)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.addChild(HtmlDocumentRenderer.java:185)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.createAndAddRendererSubTree(RootElement.java:377)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:106)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:160)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.HtmlTagWorker.processBlockChild(HtmlTagWorker.java:188)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.HtmlTagWorker.processTagChild(HtmlTagWorker.java:154)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.BodyTagWorker.processTagChild(BodyTagWorker.java:111)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:353)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:337)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:209)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:183)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:161)
    at com.test.html2pdf.main(html2pdf.java:14)
```

Comment: I don't know who added a close vote but I don't think that's appropriate any more. All the basic requirements are met: (1) simplest possible code to reproduce (2) passing input (3) failing input (4) exact error (stacktrace). The only thing that's missing, is the exact version of iText itself, but I don't think we need that, given the version of pdfHTML.

Answer (score 2):

The problematic piece of CSS here is `style="position: absolute; top: 100px;"`. Your body is pretty large for an element to be positioned on one page, and absolute positioning with page breaks is an opinion-based thing. While iText could have handled this case more gracefully, you may still try a different way of adding some spacing (e.g. with margins), and that should do the trick for you.

Visual result I've got when removed the problematic CSS pointed above:

[image: result]